# Spring boot/Spring data jpa - how to update related entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ProfileContacts profileContacts;

...

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile_contacts")
public class ProfileContacts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

}
```

I am trying to update it by sending this JSON with update to REST controller:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "description": "an update",
        "profileContacts": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
 }
```

so in the end it calls

```
profileRepository.save(profile);
```

where `profileRepository` is instance of `ProfileRepository` class:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, Long> {
}
```

which is `spring-data-jpa` interface.

But each time after such update it updates `profile` table but adds **new** row to `profile_contacts` table (table which corresponds to `ProfileContacts`entity) instead of updating existing ones.
How can I achieve updating?

Comment: Can you post the `profile` object content?

Comment: It adds new line means? New record?

Comment: @SandeshaJ I added more info pls take a look

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 New row to the table.

Comment: no id or not existing id -> "create",  existing id -> "update" (?;) (talking about nested "profileContacts" (json) element)

Comment: problem is probably in your controller handling the update, so show us the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your JSON structure. Yes it will create new `profileContacts` entry for every time.

The problem every time while saving `profile` entity you are passing `"id": 1` that means Hibernate can identify the entity by this `id` value (primary key) but for `profileContacts` mapping you are not sending the `id` that's why Hibernate considering it has a new entity every time.

To update your `profileContacts` entity make sure to pass the id of it.

*Example:*

```
{ 
"id": 1,
 "description": "an update", 
"profileContacts": {
"id" : yourEntityId
 "firstName": "John", 
"lastName": "Doe" 
}
 }
```

Comment: Won't this allow the client to update any personalContact by simply passing along a random `EntityId`?

Comment: If the random number matches persisted entity id (database entry) then it will update.
but we can restrict this by cascading I think so.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's the expected behavior.

You're not telling hibernate to update the `profileContacts`.

For the framework to be able to update it, you need to send the `profileContact`'s primary key - which in your case is the `ProfileContacts#id`.

Something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "description": "an update",
  "profileContacts": {
    "id": 1
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Need to specify the join column in the parent Entity.
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
**@JoinColumn(name = "id")** //
private ProfileContacts profileContacts;

...

}
Now when you try to save Profile entity it will save the child entity also.
```

And also needs to include Id in jason request for child entity also
{
        "id": 1,
        "description": "an update",
        "profileContacts": {
            **"id": 1,**
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
 }

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see the problem. As @Matheus Cirillo pointed out, you need to tell the hibernate to update the row.

Now, how do you tell the hibernate to update a row - By providing the primary key of the existing row.

But, creating an object with the primary key set is not enough. You need that entity class to be attached to the entity manager and the persistence context.

You can have something like,

```
//This attaches the entity to the entity manager
ProfileContacts existingProfileContacts = profileContactRepository.getOne(2);
Profile profile = new Profile();
....
....
profile.setProfileContacts(existingProfileContacts);
profileRepository.save(profile);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make an entity object and assign the filtered email and set the value to the entity object.

```
User user2 = registrationRepo.findByEmail(newPasswordDTO.getEmail());
             user2.setPassword(newPasswordDTO.getPassword());
             registrationRepo.save(user2);
```